# ng2 smart table response code handle request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng2-smart-table

I am using Ng2 -Smart table for the server side pagination ,that i customized post request to the server .The server responds with the data along with rescode.Based on the rescode i needs to load the data to the smart table i,e

```
    source: PostServerDataSource; 
this.source1 = new PostServerDataSource(this.http, {
          endPoint: this.service.apiURL + 'report/failureFileReport', dataKey: 'data', pagerLimitKey: "_limit",
          pagerPageKey: "_page",
          sortDirKey: "pageable",
          sortFieldKey: "pageable",
          totalKey: 'totalElements',
        }, request);
        if(this.source1.rescode === '0000'){
          this.source =this.source1.data;
        }  else if (this.source1.rescode == "0001") {
          this.toastyService.error(this.source1.ErrorDescription);
        } else if (this.source1.rescode == "0002") {
          this.toastyService.error(this.source1.ErrorDescription);
        }
```

This is a customized ServerDataSource for post request

```
export  class PostServerDataSource extends ServerDataSource {
        currentUser:any;
        params: any;
        sridharan:any;
        constructor(http: HttpClient, config: any, params?: any) {
            super(http, config);
            this.params = params;
        }
        protected requestElements(): Observable<any> {
            let httpParams = this.createRequesParams();
            if (this.params) {
              let keys = Object.keys(this.params);
              keys.forEach((key) => {
                  httpParams = httpParams.set(key, this.params[key]);
              });
            }
            const data = Object.assign(this.params, httpParams);
            return this.http.post(this.conf.endPoint, httpParams, { observe: 'response' })
        }
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing ? can you add a sample demo using stackblitz